# How to launch Settings app when application is not connected to internet

Tags: android, android-intent

I am building an application that uses the permission

`android.permission.Internet`

as i want to launch data from a mysql database and populate a list view. When i am connected to the internet the app starts fine but when i am not it gives me an error and says the application has stopped working. How is it possible when i'm not connected to wifi or data to give an alert to the user that will give him a chance to open the settings app and open wifi or data???

Comment: i rolled the question back to the previous status, since the edit was unclear for new posible users, since it was medway to the solution. Now the question is clear, and the accepted solution would be useful to new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if there is connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

getActiveNetworkInfo is the best function you can use, since it already checks if there is any connection, you dont have to care about wifi or data or any details, since just give you the current active connection or null if there is nothing, and this is the best when you just need to know if there is any connection regardless or which one it is.

As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)

> Returns details about the currently active default data network. When
>   connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections.
>   You should always check isConnected() before initiating network
>   traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.

you need the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

if it is not connected, you can open the wireless settings page of the device, by:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

for showing the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
bld.setMessage("The text you want to show");
    bld.setTitle(tit);
    bld.setPositiveButton(positiveButton, positiveOrNeutralCallback);

 bld.setNegativeButton("text for cancel button",new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

      bld.setPositiveButton("text for open settings button",new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            }
        });


}
 bld.create().show();
```

**update**

your code would be:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
  registerCallClickBack();


 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
         .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null
         && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();


if (!network_connected)
  onDetectNetworkState().show();
 }


public AlertDialog onDetectNetworkState(){
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder1.setMessage("text for message")
.setTitle("text for title")
.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
})       
.setPositiveButton("Οκ",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
    }
});
    return builder1.create();
}
```

Comment: you can do it whereever you need it. In onCreate could be ok if that is what you need.

Comment: i must be doing something wrong can u check this out???? i am not actually checking if i am connected and whats the value of network_connected variable..how is this possible to manage???

Comment: there you are. check my update. You check the conection inside the onCreate. if not connected, you call your `onDetectNetworkState()` also i changed the context.startActivity to just startActivity, since you are already inside a context

Comment: well again it says force close. i did everything you said but it doesnt respond..even if i am connected or not it says stopped working...

Comment: you have any other problem.  but thats a different question. it is better to open a new one since here we will be mixing too much things (this one is about checking the conection, the dialog, and open the settings). please, accept this one, open a new question where you put the logcat and you explain that even if i you connected or not it says stopped working. then if you want came here an paste the link as a comment an i will take a look at it

Comment: there you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455867/check-whether-its-connected-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You can check Internet connectivity using

```
  public static boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context)
{
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if(wifi.isAvailable()||mobile.isAvailable())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

To launch Settings use

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);`

Answer (score 0):

In combination with Carlos answer, you should check if you connected to your server. 
You can do it like this:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = null;
NetworkInfo netInfo    = null;

cm = (ConnectivityManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
  //we are connected to a network but can we connect to our server?
  //let's ping it
  Socket socket = null;
  try {

   socket = new Socket();
   if (socket != null) {

   socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("yourServer.com", 80),   5000);                                 
   // we have reached our server --> lets get the data we want                              

   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    //Connectivity YES, Connection to server NO --> no data load
   } catch (IOException e) {
    //Connectivity YES, Connection to server NO --> no data load
   }
}
```