# Check whether its connected or not

Tags: android, android-intent

The logcat output is this..

```
 01-30 06:34:43.633: D/AndroidRuntime(1228): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    01-30 06:34:43.643: D/AndroidRuntime(1228): CheckJNI is ON
    01-30 06:34:43.703: D/dalvikvm(1228): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:43.713: D/dalvikvm(1228): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:43.733: D/dalvikvm(1228): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:43.743: D/dalvikvm(1228): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:43.743: D/dalvikvm(1228): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
    01-30 06:34:43.933: D/dalvikvm(1228): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
    01-30 06:34:44.463: E/memtrack(1228): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    01-30 06:34:44.463: E/android.os.Debug(1228): failed to load memtrack module: -2
    01-30 06:34:44.743: D/AndroidRuntime(1228): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    01-30 06:34:44.783: D/AndroidRuntime(1228): Shutting down VM
    01-30 06:34:44.783: D/dalvikvm(1228): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    01-30 06:34:45.503: D/AndroidRuntime(1239): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    01-30 06:34:45.503: D/AndroidRuntime(1239): CheckJNI is ON
    01-30 06:34:45.563: D/dalvikvm(1239): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:45.573: D/dalvikvm(1239): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:45.593: D/dalvikvm(1239): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:45.593: D/dalvikvm(1239): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
    01-30 06:34:45.603: D/dalvikvm(1239): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
    01-30 06:34:45.863: D/dalvikvm(1239): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
    01-30 06:34:46.373: E/memtrack(1239): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    01-30 06:34:46.373: E/android.os.Debug(1239): failed to load memtrack module: -2
    01-30 06:34:46.653: D/AndroidRuntime(1239): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    01-30 06:34:46.723: I/ActivityManager(379): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/.MainActivity} from pid 1239
    01-30 06:34:46.763: E/gralloc_goldfish(50): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 328 x 583, usage 333
    01-30 06:34:46.763: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(50): alloc(328, 583, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
    01-30 06:34:46.763: E/(50): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=328, h=583) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
    01-30 06:34:46.763: E/BufferQueue(379): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
    01-30 06:34:46.763: W/WindowManager(379): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21005
    01-30 06:34:46.783: D/AndroidRuntime(1239): Shutting down VM
    01-30 06:34:46.803: D/jdwp(1239): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
    01-30 06:34:46.803: D/dalvikvm(1239): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    01-30 06:34:46.833: D/dalvikvm(1250): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    01-30 06:34:46.833: I/ActivityManager(379): Start proc com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions for activity com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/.MainActivity: pid=1250 uid=10054 gids={50054, 3003}
    01-30 06:34:47.513: D/dalvikvm(1250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 4% free 3137K/3256K, paused 57ms, total 59ms
    01-30 06:34:47.533: I/dalvikvm-heap(1250): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.202MB for 1127536-byte allocation
    01-30 06:34:47.603: D/dalvikvm(1250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4235K/4360K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
    01-30 06:34:47.813: D/AndroidRuntime(1250): Shutting down VM
    01-30 06:34:47.813: W/dalvikvm(1250): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1b06ba8)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): Process: com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions, PID: 1250
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    01-30 06:34:47.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     ... 11 more
    01-30 06:34:47.823: W/ActivityManager(379):   Force finishing activity com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/.MainActivity
    01-30 06:34:48.013: D/dalvikvm(1250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 217K, 6% free 4532K/4816K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
    01-30 06:34:48.243: I/WindowManager(379): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b215f238 ActivityRecord{b2373780 u0 com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/.MainActivity t6 f}} appWin=Window{b22ec3a8 u0 Starting com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions} drawState=4
    01-30 06:34:48.243: W/WindowManager(379): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (720x1280) to layer 21010
    01-30 06:34:48.773: W/ActivityManager(379): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b2373780 u0 com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/.MainActivity t6 f}
    01-30 06:34:48.883: W/EGL_emulation(540): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-30 06:34:49.933: D/LightsService(379): Excessive delay setting light: 218ms
    01-30 06:34:50.033: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.033: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.033: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.033: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.033: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.033: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.053: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.063: W/InputMethodManagerService(379): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b2385490 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b20c9ac8
    01-30 06:34:50.073: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.073: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.073: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.073: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.073: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.073: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.083: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.083: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    01-30 06:34:50.083: W/AudioService(379): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
    01-30 06:34:50.083: I/Process(1250): Sending signal. PID: 1250 SIG: 9
    01-30 06:34:50.103: D/LightsService(379): Excessive delay setting light: 124ms
    01-30 06:34:50.113: I/ActivityManager(379): Process com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions (pid 1250) has died.
    01-30 06:34:50.113: I/WindowState(379): WIN DEATH: Window{b23292d0 u0 com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions/com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity}
    01-30 06:34:50.203: D/LightsService(379): Excessive delay setting light: 109ms
```

and my code is...when i try to run it says has stopped working...i have the permission access_network_state in the manifest. can anyone point me what i am doing wrong??what i want to do is when the app starts to detect if there is network connection and if it is to do what i do in onCreate, if it isnt to create an alert dialog and when user presses ok to launch the settings wifi page to be able to turn the wifi on.. please help me...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://spinner.bl.ee/getstocks.php";
 private ListView listView;
 ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Activity context;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
  onDetectConnected();
  registerCallClickBack();
 }

 public void onDetectConnected(){
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
             .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null
             && activeNetwork.isAvailable();
        if(!network_connected){
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        }
 }

public AlertDialog onDetectNetworkState(){
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder1.setMessage("Εντοπίστηκε πρόβλημμα με τη σύνδεση στο διαδύκτιο. Παρακαλώ συνδεθήτε στο διαδύκτιο.")
.setTitle("Χωρίς σύνδεση δικτύου")
.setNegativeButton("Άκυρο",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
})       
.setPositiveButton("Οκ",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
    }
});
    return builder1.create();
}

 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     onCreateDialogBack().show();
}
public AlertDialog onCreateDialogBack(){
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setMessage(R.string.exit_message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
}
private void registerCallClickBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String message = "Έχετε επιλέξει την " + id + "η μετοχή";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Γίνεται Λήψη μετοχών...");
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         pDialog.show();

     }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   ListDrwaer();
   pDialog.dismiss();
  }

 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> stocksList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
    String id = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
    String outPut =id + ") " + name + " - " + number;
    stocksList.add(createStockList("metoxes", outPut));
   }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, stocksList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "metoxes" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createStockList(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);

  return employeeNameNo;
 }
}
```

my manifest file is this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_stock"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

from what it seems i have the problem here

```
01-30 07:10:19.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity.onDetectConnected(MainActivity.java:58)
01-30 07:10:19.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):     at com.ptuxiaki.stockpredictions.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
```

line 53 is:

```
onDetectConnected();
```

line 58 is:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
             .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: have u added Internet permission???

Comment: what do you have in MainActivity.java line 55?

Comment: at which line you got error? post it

Comment: how do i post the line???where do i see the line numbers???sorry i am new in android coding...

Comment: the error is in line 55. in eclipse, in the left side of the editor you have the line numbers. please copy the code that is in the line 55 and paste it here

Comment: yeah, i already figured it out reading your oncreate. your updated confirmed what i thought. please look at my answer  below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
 private Activity context;
```

and everywhere when you are using it, also remove it. For instance change

```
 context.getSystemService(...
```

to just

```
  getSystemService(...
```

your MainActivity is already a Context, and that is what you need. 
You created context field, but is is null, and anyways that wont work since you need a context created by the systems. and that is what your activity is.

Comment: well now that i removed the context it works if i am connected...but if i close the internet connection it says force close again...i shows the alert dialog but it says has stopped working and closes immediatelly...

Comment: probably you have an error on registerCallClickBack(); if there is not conection, you should not execute any other code. please let your network_connected be a field of the class, instead a variable inside a function, and check it again before calling registerCallClickBack();

Comment: this method is called only when i click an item in list view. i dont think that there is a problem there since it works with wifi on. when i close the wifi or data and i am not connected it shows the dialog but it also says has stopped working...can u help me out??? i will paste the code the context removed so that you can check it out...

Comment: or better, dont use the function  onDetectConnected(), put all that code in your onCreate directly. so you can do  if(!network_connected){
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        }
else registerCallClickBack();

Comment: ok. so i guess you dont even see the dialog if there is not connection, rigth? please, i would need also the new logcat.

Comment: i just fixed the way you proposed...thanks a lot man...you saved me today...this is a project for uni...cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission...

```
    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```